# Uncaught TypeError undefined is not a function anonymous function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am new to JS, and have bumped into a problem. Album results in an error, which is listed below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function script.js?ver=1.0:12
(anonymous function) script.js?ver=1.0:12
n.extend.each jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:1
n.fn.n.each jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:1
initialise script.js?ver=1.0:12
jQuery.ajax.success loader.js?ver=1.0:9
j jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:1
k.fireWith jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:1
x jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:1
bjquery.js?ver=1.11.0:1
```

Upon reloading the page however, everything works. What can be the problem?

I have included a script.js code segment (that can also be seen through developer tools) that seems to be problematic. Please let me know if I need to include my .php file.

```
/*---------------------------------------------- 
               F L E X S L I D E R
------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(content+' .slider').each(function(index){
    var thisid = jQuery(this).attr('id');   
        jQuery("#"+thisid+" .flexslider").flexslider({ - This line is causing error
        controlsContainer: "#"+thisid,
        animation: "fade",
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        animationDuration: 600,
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true,
        smoothHeight: true,
        touch: true,
        video: true,
        randomize: false
    }); //end flexslider
});
```

Comment: I don't see that error. It would help a lot if you could identify exactly what line of code is causing the error; the developer tools should tell you that.

Comment: Your page *does* get a warning from "rocket.js" to the effect that your version of Modernizr is out of date.

Comment: @Pointy Developer tools on Google Chrome is telling me that line 12 on script.js is faulty. I'll edit the original post and show some more code

Comment: @user3811284 And, which line in the snippet is line 12 in the file?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I have edited the original post to include line 12, which is var offset = window.pageYOffset;

Comment: What is the variable `content`? Is it a class name or does it contain element type like `div` or something? If it is not an element type... then it the first line should be `jQuery(content+' slider').each(function(index){`(no dot, because I think you are trying to select multiple classes) and if it is a element name like `div` the it should be `jQuery(content+'.slider').each(function(index){` (no space)

Comment: Check, you have an extra space before ".flexslider"- jQuery("#"+thisid+" .flexslider". May be its causing problem

Comment: replace this jQuery("#"+thisid+" .flexslider").flexslider({ with jQuery("#"+thisid+".flexslider").flexslider({

Comment: @HarpreetSingh I tired that, but all it does is remove the side arrows.

Comment: @j809 it has an element name, however by removing the spaces, all I do is remove the slide arrows.

Comment: @imguru I tired that, but all it does is remove the side arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting line 12 is because the script.js file is being "compressed" by removing all unnecessary white space. If you use the "pretty print" icon ( looks like this {} ) in the lower left corner of the JS source view in the Developer tools window you'll actually see that it is the following code giving you problems:

```
jQuery("#" + thisid + " .flexslider").flexslider({controlsContainer: "#" +
thisid,animation: "fade",slideshowSpeed: 7000,animationDuration: 600,
slideshow: false,directionNav: true,controlNav: true,smoothHeight: true,
touch: true,video: true,randomize: false});
```

The cause of this is most likely that the flexslider function is trying to be called before it's actually loaded from the flexslider script. Ensure that the flexslider script is loaded before the function is called and this should fix your problem.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how would I go about on doing that? I use the same code for my "weddings" page, and everything loads fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... didn't see your comment until now. You can wrap the whole foreach loop with a jQuery(document).ready(function(){}); This would ensure that the code doesn't run until the dom is fully loaded.